# Which language to a write a linux distro GUI installer

Tags: linux, installation

I was wondering, which programming language I should use if I want to make a GUI installer for a Linux Distro?  Is it GTK? or ? 
Something like this: http://www.castellan.net/linux_firewall/fedora_install_1.jpg more or less. 
It's for ArchLinux I want to try.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any language for which there are bindings for a GUI toolkit supported on your target platform.  Some examples:

- C and GTK+.
- C++ and gtkmm.
- C++ and Qt.
- C# and Gtk#.
- Python and PyGTK.
- Python and PyQt.

This is by no means an exhaustive list.

In other words: start with a language you are comfortable with, and see if there is a usable GUI toolkit available for it, either natively-implemented in that language or through bindings.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into that :-) I'm a bit confused about launching a GUI from a terminal in a none X enviroment.